# How to create a smaller dataframe from an existing dataframe by looping through existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called df with many rows and 12 columns.  Column 10 is a column called METRIC_ID1.  How do I loop through df to create a new df that only contains rows where the METRIC_ID1 value is 'sales_yoy'?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please do some research before asking a question here. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ways-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-by-column-values/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to explicitly loop the DataFrame, you can just save a filtered DataFrame in another variable. You can achieve this with:

```
new_df = df[df['METRIC_ID1'] == 'sales_yoy']
```

If you really want to loop through df, this is a way of doing it:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['METRIC_ID1'] == 'sales_yoy':
        new_df.loc[len(new_df)] = row
```